# Solving Memory Leaks in Large React Application

Tags: reactjs, memory-leaks

I've been scavenging the internet for the last week lately trying to figure out how to spot and solve memory leaks within my React application, because well, I think I have a memory leak in my application.  I've noticed that our application crashes more and more frequently lately and I continue to get the same error from Node.js: `API fatal error handler returned after process out of memory`.  I knew that the application that I was working on developed by others before me had some serious flaws, but never knew that they were this bad, so I decided to turn to the internet to try and solve this issue.

I looked at the `Chrome Dev Tools` and taking heap snapshots to see if there is an increase in memory and it is apparent that there is when I see the memory shoot from 123MB to 200+MB after a few actions within the application.  Now this is a good tool for determining whether there is a possible memory leak or not, but it's absolutely hard to read and understand, which doesn't help me determine where the issues lye.

Now our AWS instance is only 1GB in size and a lot of answers I see about this sort of issue is to just increase the max space of Node.js but that doesn't solve any issues, instead it just throws a band-aid on it until the issue occurs again, which is not good practice in my opinion.  I'm coming here now in hopes that someone can help me understand what in the world I'm looking at when using the `Chrome Dev Tools`, and/or if someone knows a better way in finding out where the issues are in my code that would be very helpful as well. Thanks In Advance.

**EDIT**

Out of all of the most common issues with memory leaks in javascript that I have read online, there aren't any that stick out to me within our application, so I'm very confused on were the possible leak is coming from.

Another thing is that the application is grabbing a lot of data from our backend and keeping it in memory.  Could minimizing the amount of data that is retrieved help, or would that only slow down the issue instead of fixing it?

Comment: It looks like the memory leak is in the Node.js app rather than the client app. You first need to identify this. This problem is difficult to debug without additional information. You can start from looking at the logs in the nodejs application. "API OUT OF MEMORY" might be an error thrown from your code or a library that you use.

Comment: @nipuna777 Are you saying that the memory leak is coming from the Node.js portion of my application instead of the React portion?  Also "API fatal error handler returned after process out of memory" is an error from Node.js saying that it failed to GC because it couldn't allocate memory for it.

Comment: Yes, that error looks to be completely independent from the client side(React app). You should be able to debug that to see where the memory leak is.

Comment: @nipuna777 if that's the case, then I think that helps narrow things down a bit more.  Is there an efficient way to debug the Node.js parts of my application?

Comment: Unfortunately these are tricky to track down. You can try following some guides on getting better logs and monitoring in first so that you can attempt to identify the issue. As a temporary fix, you could have the server to automatically restart when memory is low as well.

Comment: @nipuna777 I did look into something like ```pm2``` which would do that exactly, but I'm really adamant on trying to solve these issues instead of putting a band-aid on them so that they don't happen again.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. in case of finding a solution please update the question.

Comment: @Michael My question is how to find the page containing the memory leak?  Do I need to take snapshots for all pages I have in some period of time ? or better solution ?

Comment: any update on this issue?  I am facing same issue in my org . Is there a recommended way to detect memory usage in our application

Comment: @atom217 Memory usage can be seen from the Memory tab in the developer tools of a browser.

Comment: @atom217 there were ultimately a few things that I did to resolve this:
1. reduced amount of data being retrieved by API calls
2. upgraded micro AWS EC2 instance to small
3. overall code refactor to ensure no var primatives were being used and strictly tried to use const anywhere I could

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with the react application in my organization. React application received huge data from the Api and it stored the data in the state variables. Based on the type of operations, the application would send back the huge data to the Api.

Due to this, the application break with `Out of Memory` issue.
The solution to the issue is not a direct one. However it involves lot of analysis on the code.

1. Try to see if the data size can be reduced.
2. Deep dive to see if you could use useMemo in the child components which are getting re-rendered everytime a parent component re-renders.
3. If there is need to modify the small part of the state in the application, try using [Immutability Helper](https://reactjs.org/docs/update.html) and [Immer](https://reactjs.org/docs/update.html)

In my application, I tried reducing the size of the response where ever it was applicable and used immer to modify the state. I don't see the `Out of Memory` issue in the application after the changes.